# Aligning text in LyX: left/center/right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx

How can I center/right/left align text in LyX? In Microsoft Word, I can just click the 
3 buttons on the toolbar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Horizontal alignment is associated with a paragraph style in LyX. Select the paragraph, click `Edit`>`Paragraph Settings...` (or click the [image: LyX paragraph settings button] button in the toolbar) and choose one of the *Alignment* options:

[image: LyX paragraph settings]

Click *OK* or *Apply* for the selection to take effect. Checking *Immediate Apply* allows one to toggle and visualize the difference between selected options.

---

For inserting horizontal fill (or `\hfill`; which also leads to a flush left and flush right formatting on the same line), you follow `Insert`>`Formatting`>`Horizontal Space...` and for the *Spacing* choose `Horizontal Fill`:

[image]

Upon clicking *OK*, your document will show the horizontal fill as a stretchable dotted line which shrinks/expands to fit the window

[image]

and eventually typesets/compiles to

[image]

A similar output would have been obtain through the insertion of "TeX code":

[image]

Comment: That works. However when I try aligning "within" certain parts of text, those options move all the text. For example, on a certain line, I want to right align some text and left align others. How can I do that?

Comment: @GTyler: Yes, that's why they are called "paragraph settings", so they apply to an entire paragraph. If you want to have left- and right-aligned text in the same "line", and that line is a paragraph, then you can insert `\hfill` between the text components. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @GTyler For reference, `\hfill` is in LyX found in Insert --> Formatting --> Horizontal space. Choose "Horizontal fill" for Spacing.

Comment: Yes that's what I am after. Since I am still new to Lyx, I prefer the click-and-choose rather than remembering LaTex code.

Comment: @GTyler: I've added that description to my answer.

Comment: Actually I would like to apply it to the whole document. How would I do this?

Comment: @Nobody: And by "apply it" you mean applying some paragraph justification for the entire document? The default is "Justified". If you want something else, I'd suggest adding it to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble: `\raggedright` for Left, `\centering` for Center, `\raggedleft` for Right.

Answer (score 1):

Select all the lines that you need to align (middle/left/right).
Then right click and under text style select structure
Now, the whole part is one structure
Again select this complete structure
Next, use paragraph settings to align the texts :)

Comment: As it seems, this solution is working for mathematical statements. You are welcome to tweak the solution to fit your purpose

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. I don't see a *Structure* under *Text style* in the right click menu when right clicking on selected text.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and fastest way is: once you are in the desired place just click on the "TEX" button (next to the hyperlink one) and in the box just add the following:

```
\hfill
```

To have dots between just do:

```
\dotfill
```

And to have a line:

```
\hrulefill
```

You can find more information here: http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you explain how your solution is different from the last part of [Werner's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40199/21344)?

Comment: @PaulGessler I just updated my answer. I think it adds more information.